# Размещение картинки в блоке

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы картинки (разных размеров) занимали полностью блоки с неопределенными параметры (высота и ширина не заданы)? 
Картинки помещены в блок `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно оформить картинку как фон и растянуть...

В сниппете ниже одна картинка вставляется в блоки разных размеров. CSS свойство `background-size: cover;` делает так, чтобы фоновая картинка полностью покрывала пространство контейнера (растягивалась или сжималась, соблюдая пропорции картинки). Главный минус в том, что в некоторых случаях не будет видна вся картинка - все зависит от параметров контейнера.

```css
.blockWbg {
  background-image: url(http://icdn1.digitaltrends.com/image/google-logo-feature-1030x686.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.b1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.b2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.b3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
.b4 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockWbg b1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="blockWbg b2">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="blockWbg b3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="blockWbg b4">&nbsp;</div>
```

У свойства `background-size:` есть еще вариант `background-size: contain;`. Он делает так, что фоновая картинка вставляется в контейнер так, чтобы полностью в нем помещаться. Но он не всегда удобен, потому что в случаях, когда пропорции контейнера не совпадают с пропорциями картинки, будут пустые места.

---

Если Вы не против потери пропорций картинки, то вот другой вариант.
Здесь без фона. Картинка растягивается на 100% ширину и высоту заданного блока. Пропорции могут потеряться...

```css
.imgW {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.imgW>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgW">
  <img src="http://www.survey-reviews.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google_logo_small.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Задать для картинки:

html:

```
<div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <img src='/'>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2zn42hp5/)

Comment: Это не решает основную задачу: надо чтобы "картинки (разных размеров) занимали полностью блоки". В Вашем же варианте лишь абсолютное позиционирование. Добавление `bottom: 0; right: 0` не растягивает картинку...